# Can't read or create comments on facebook post once asset_feed_spec is preset on ad creative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-marketing-api

I have an app that reads comments on ads from facebooks api,

During testing we've noticed that when the user adds any variations to the ad this creates an asset_feed_spec on the adcreative, which then creates several other ad creatives to match the asset_feed_spec.

The issue is once the asset_feed_spec is present you can no longer read or create comments on the effective_object_story_id for the  adcreative that is listed under {ad_account_id}/ads?fields=adcreatives.

- The api does allow you to read and post comments but they do not show on the ad anymore. The api  will return any created comments but the ad wont show them.

Interestingly if you go to {ad_account_id}/adcreatives you can see the new creatives that was created, and you can post and create comments to the first of the new variations created and these will show on the ad and any new ads created.

However these new ad creatives have no link i can find back to the original ad they was created from, so theres no way to actually read or post comments for an ad.

All i'm trying todo is read comments and post comments to any newly created ads, its amazing facebook has made this so difficult.

I've attached two examples:

Example One,

You can see the api returns many comments for this ad.  But when you visit the permalink url on the ad creative there's only one comment "manual test" which i added manually,

Example Two,

You can see the ad should have 12 comments, the api returns 0 for that page post id

This issue only occurs when the asset_feed_spec exists on the ad creative -> effective_object_story_id

Had 0 help from facebook support forum as expected but have seen many reporting the same issue,

Has anyone found a solution?

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. The effective_object_story_id read provided by API is completely different then the actual ad post where comment is posted.

Comment: were you able to found any solution?